# How to set a primary key in table for postgres using dataframes in pandas?

Tags: postgresql, pandas

I want to store a table into postgres 8.4 (edited previously stated:8.1) using 
pandas.DataFrame.to_sql
via sqlalchemy using the following command.

```
df.to_sql("table_name",engine)
```

I am using postgres. How can I get set a PRIMARY KEY in this table that I am adding to the database? I tried to use the option index in the df.to_sql however, that does not seem to work.

Comment: Postgres 8.1 is more than 10 years old and is not supported. Please consider updating to a supported postgres  version.

Comment: I don't have a DF-specific answer, but you can always add the primary key after the fact.

Comment: Hi, I am using 8.4.20. sorry about that. If it is not DF specific, how can it be changed after the fact...that may be just as good. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your df contains a column "id" which you want to use as PRIMARY KEY, then do this:

```
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);')
```

Comment: Note that this will also work if you have created say a serial primary key in the table beforehand.  index=False will allow you to insert the other cols.  The primary key will auto-increment.